# How can I split a string based on two delimiters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, split, vue-component

My code like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <p v-for="club in clubs">{{club}}</p>
    ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    clubs: ''
  }),
  mounted () {
    let dataClub =  "- City\n - MU\n - Liverpool\n - Arsenal\n - Chelsea"
    // let dataClub =  "City;MU;Liverpool;Arsenal;Chelsea"
    let dc = dataClub.split('\n')
    this.clubs = dc
  }
}
</script>
```

dataClub is dynamic. It can be separated with `;` and can also be separated with `\n`

How can I do a split if there are 2 separators?

Comment: Not a good solution but you can replace one with the other then split on the other: `dataClub.replace(/\n/g, ';').split(';')`. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with RegEx:

```
let dc = dataClub.split(/[\n;]/)
```

Comment: I want to add 1 more separator, which is `\\t`. How do I do that? Is it like this :let dc = dataClub.split(/[\n;\\t]/)?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a regular expression between either `;` or `\n`:

```js
const doSplit = str => str.split(/;|\n/);

console.log(doSplit("- City\n - MU\n - Liverpool\n - Arsenal\n - Chelsea"));
console.log(doSplit("City;MU;Liverpool;Arsenal;Chelsea"));
```

Comment: I want to add 1 more separator, which is `\\t`. How do I do that? Is it like this : `const doSplit = str => str.split(/;|\n|\\t/);`?